# C# MongoDB driver - Change array item position?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I wonder if there is a way to change an item's position in an array using C# MongoDB driver?

For example, I have this document:

```
{
    "Item": "X",
    "Values": [
        {
            "Value": 1
        },
        {
            "Value": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to change the order of the items in the `Values` array let's say:

```
{
    "Item": "X",
    "Values": [
        {
            "Value": 2
        },
        {
            "Value": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

what I'm currently doing is using `PullFilter` to remove `"value": 2"` and then use `PushEach` to insert it at the specific position I need.

But in my case, the array items are large objects so I was wondering if there is a way to just change the item's position without having to remove and re-insert it again.

Comment: Are you trying to fix the data to have sorted order in array ? Something like `db.col.update(    { },    { $push: { Values: { $each: [], $sort: {Value:-1}}}})` should work.

Comment: The final goal is to have it sorted, by I don't want to use a sort index. I'm using the array index as my sort.